# General approach to isometrics

Tags: isometric, tilemap

I am currently discovering the world of isometrics, now I found out there are two approaches to creating the tilemap;

1. Just create 2:1 ratio tile-images and draw those.
2. Creating squares and transforming them to the 2:1 ratio. What is the general approach on developing an isometric game?

Now I was wondering a few things;

- How do more known games like AOE1/2 do this?
- What are the pros/cons of both methods?
- Which method is preferred to be used in this day and age?

**Edit added more general question**

Comment: Why does it matter how AOE1/2 does this?

Comment: Because I think AOE is a perfect example of how a game using isometrics should look/work/feel.

Comment: AOE supported a maximum screen resolution of 1024x768.  And didn't support 16:9 resolutions at all.  My feeling is that good technical choices 15 years ago do not necessarily translate to good technical choices today, so there's only a limited amount of practical wisdom to be gleaned by examining the techniques used in implementing the games from that era.  (unlike their designs, which are often still quite relevant)

Comment: True, I added another question to the list..

Comment: Did you even read my answer? This site requires you to give feedback - please do so by voting/accepting or commenting, or both. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did this, so I might be wrong with all of this. But I have a pretty good understanding of graphics programming, so here are my thoughts:

- When AOE 1/2 were written, memory and disk space were valuable. A 2:1 tile-image is bigger than a square which is transformed.
- If you draw squares and transform them, you do not have pixel-perfect control over you final image.
- ... but it is easier to create tilable 2D sprites as squares.
- transforming a square to an isometric tile is not necessarily trivial

I for myself would do the first approach (2:1 tiles), because it is easier to implement...

Comment: Of course I read your answer (forgot to +1 it), I understand 2:1 tiles are easier to implement and because of that it would be your method of choice but I was wondering what the general approach to isometrics is and why. There are a lot of isometric games out there  but I find it hard to find information about how and especially WHY that way. (and I understand how stackexchange sites work, been around on sites like stackoverflow for a while now)

Comment: Well then, I guess, there is no real answer to your question. I think there is no such thing as "the general approach", people have always found different solutions with different pros and cons. As I said, I would go for 2:1, simply because it is easier. If your framework can transform you graphics tiles, you can just as well use that (e.g. use OpenGL with an isometric camera transform matrix).